# Save data in userStorage outside the Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an app (developed using Xamarin) that when the user logs in for the first time, generates some info about the user.

I need to save this information in the userStorage of Google Assistant so that I can get this information in the inline editor for fulfillments of the Dialogflow.

I already have the code that gets the info from the userStorage:

```
let userStorage = request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user.userStorage || JSON.stringify({});
let uninterId;

userStorage = JSON.parse(userStorage);

if (userStorage.hasOwnProperty('uninterId')) {
    uninterId = userStorage.uninterId;
}
```

Now I need to know how I can make my app save that information through my Android app.

Is it possible to save data on the userStorage outside from the Google Assistant?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User storage is only available to you within your action. If you are interested in having this data available outside the context of your action, you may want to consider a third-party database service like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer